# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CUSTOM DATA TYPE>

Tags: c#, linq

I call a `GetData` call which returned a `IQueryable` object. I used the following LINQ `SelectMany` to filter out and selected the fields which I need to 
return a `List<MyDataType>` and I get the following error

**Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collection.Generic.List<MyDataType>`**

Here is my code

```
List<CASES> caseList = cs.GetData(foiaNumber).ToList();

Dictionary<int, string> NameDict = 
    caseList.ToDictionary(cases => cases.UID, cases =>     cases.NAME);


List<MyDataType> bindingGrdList = 
    caseList.SelectMany(x => x.ListObject)
        .Select(n => 
            new { 
                   SUBMITTER_NAME = NameDict[n.UID], 
                   NUMBER = n.UID, 
                   DATE_SENT = n.DATE_SENT, 
                   DATE_DUE = n.DATE_DUE, 
                   FINAL_DETERMINATION = n.FINAL_DETERMINATION 
                 }).ToList();
```

How do I fix the AnonymousType error? thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace

```
n => new { SUBMITTER_NAME = NameDict[n.UID], NUMBER = n.UID,
    DATE_SENT = n.DATE_SENT, DATE_DUE = n.DATE_DUE,
    FINAL_DETERMINATION = n.FINAL_DETERMINATION }
```

with

```
n => new MyDataType { SUBMITTER_NAME = NameDict[n.UID], NUMBER = n.UID,
    DATE_SENT = n.DATE_SENT, DATE_DUE = n.DATE_DUE,
    FINAL_DETERMINATION = n.FINAL_DETERMINATION }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var` instead:

```
var bindingGrdList = caseList.SelectMany(x => x.ListObject).Select(n => new { SUBMITTER_NAME = NameDict[n.UID], NUMBER = n.UID, DATE_SENT = n.DATE_SENT, DATE_DUE = n.DATE_DUE, FINAL_DETERMINATION = n.FINAL_DETERMINATION }).ToList();
```

This will make it infer the type from your code, which is what you want for anonymous types.

Comment: It's useful when the variable is local to method, though that most of times the result will be passed to a caller method.

Comment: The first version of his question mentioned only the type `List` for the `bindingGrdList`. There was no mention of `MyDataType` at that point. For the updated question it should be the way Rawling answered it. I'd like to note though, that for things like ASP.NET controls it can be very useful, binding data is usually of the form `object` which will swally any `DataTable` or `IEnumerable` data source. In those cases there is no need to make explicit classes.

Comment: Yeah I knew and I voted up your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the projection from an anonymous type into the `MyDataType`. To do that, you need to change the `Select` like this:

```
List<MyDataType> bindingGrdList = 
    caseList.SelectMany(x => x.ListObject)
        .Select(n => 
            new MyDataType 
                { 
                   SUBMITTER_NAME = NameDict[n.UID], 
                   NUMBER = n.UID, 
                   DATE_SENT = n.DATE_SENT, 
                   DATE_DUE = n.DATE_DUE, 
                   FINAL_DETERMINATION = n.FINAL_DETERMINATION 
                 }).ToList();
```

NOTE: I'm assuming that these properties are the correct properties for `MyDataType`, and that `MyDataType` has a default parameterless constructor.